# Split equation problem

Tags: equations, line-breaking

I would like to split the following equation in two parts. Very basic thing, seems to be.

```
\begin{equation}
\zeta_k(x) = \frac{\sin (\frac{1}{2} (x - x_0)) \cdots \sin(\frac{1}{2} (x-x_{k-1}))}
{ \sin ( \frac{1}{2} (x_k - x_0)) \cdots \sin(\frac{1}{2} (x_k - x_{k-1}))} %
%
\frac{\sin ( \frac{1}{2} (x - x_{k+1})) \cdots %
\sin(\frac{1}{2} (x - x_{2n}))}{\sin(\frac{1}{2} (x_k - x_{k+1})) \cdots %
\sin(\frac{1}{2} (x_k - x_{2n}))}
\label{eq3}
\end{equation}
```

I inserted amsmath package and tried with begin split and so on but can not get to the point where I separate the equation into two lines, one that contains

```
\zeta_k(x) = \frac{\sin (\frac{1}{2} (x - x_0)) \cdots \sin(\frac{1}{2} (x-x_{k-1}))}
{ \sin ( \frac{1}{2} (x_k - x_0)) \cdots \sin(\frac{1}{2} (x_k - x_{k-1}))} %
%
```

and the other that contains

```
\frac{\sin ( \frac{1}{2} (x - x_{k+1})) \cdots %
\sin(\frac{1}{2} (x - x_{2n}))}{\sin(\frac{1}{2} (x_k - x_{k+1})) \cdots %
\sin(\frac{1}{2} (x_k - x_{2n}))}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: What error messages are you seeing?  When I put `\begin{split} ... \\ ... \end{split}` in the right places then I get a decent output.  Can you post the exact code that you tried that _didn't_ work?

Comment: (For "the right places", see daleif's answer.)

Comment: Just a minor suggestion: to improve readability I would use `\sin\bigl(\frac{1}{2} (x - x_0)\bigr)` instead of `\sin(\frac{1}{2} (x - x_0))` (similar remark applies to all the other factors).

Comment: I realized that the problem has to do with my mac tex installation, since compilation in linux finally worked

Comment: @gnu_drug amsmath is very stable; I don't think it could be MacTeX that was the problem...

Comment: me neither, but that's the real world ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use (memoir not relevant)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\zeta_k(x) ={} & \frac{\sin (\frac{1}{2} (x - x_0)) \cdots
  \sin(\frac{1}{2} (x-x_{k-1}))} { \sin ( \frac{1}{2} (x_k - x_0))
  \cdots \sin(\frac{1}{2} (x_k - x_{k-1}))} %
 %
\\
& \times \frac{\sin ( \frac{1}{2} (x - x_{k+1})) \cdots %
  \sin(\frac{1}{2} (x - x_{2n}))}{\sin(\frac{1}{2} (x_k -
  x_{k+1})) \cdots %
  \sin(\frac{1}{2} (x_k - x_{2n}))}
\end{split}
\label{eq3}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```